# android - adb more than one device/emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I genymotion emulator and my phone connected , I want to run and debug my application over wifi , I found the instruction to do so but I get this error when I enter this code :

```
adb tcpip 5555
```

I get this error : 
error: more than one device/emulator

How can I make my device as default or something like that to solve this problem ?

Comment: Did you try 'adb -s <device ID> tcpip 5555' Device id you can get it from adb devices

Comment: `adb kill-server` fixes the problem with offline emulators

Answer (score 43):

You can send commands to a specific device, according to [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#directingcommands):

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554 device
emulator-5555 device

$ adb -s emulator-5555 do_your_command
```

Also, if only one is emulator or a real device you can just attach `-e` or `-d` and send the command to it:

> If you have multiple devices available, but only one is an emulator, use the -e option to send commands to the emulator. Likewise, if there are multiple devices but only one hardware device attached, use the -d option to send commands to the hardware device.

Comment: For some reason a command like:
`adb shell -e emulator-5556 am broadcast android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETE` doesn't work when two emulators are attached. Can't have BlueStacks and another emulator at the same time.

Answer (score 12):

Do following thing which will help you,

You getting the message just because you are connected more than one device.

Run commands

```
adb devices
```

after the fire above command, you get the list of the device, From the list select your device id which not emulator
and fire following command

```
adb -s f725aa8b7ce4(deviceId) tcpip 5555
```

and after this fire

```
adb connect yourIp 5555
```

Comment: Tried this, still showing emulator-5554 in Termux (using WiFi ADB app). Still have the issue of 'more than one device/emulator' when trying to set app permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with same issue since months, later while testing in postman I got know that "Appium inspector" is the main reason for this issue. As it creates new session Id and interrupt the running framework server.
Hence, `adb kill-server` `adb start-server` resolves the issue as it actually kill the session ID created by Appium inspector and starts new server.